# Have button action in fragment instead of main

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app where i'm using tabs (with ActionBarSherlock). So my main activity creates the tabs for me and from there i load in the fragment layouts.

In my `MainActivity.java` i create a tab (this is just a snippet):

```
mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

mTabsAdapter.addTab(
    bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1"),
    MainMenuFragment.class, null);
```

My MainMenu.java looks like this:

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public void showMainMenu(View view)
    {
        Log.e("app", "olol: button!"); // never called!!
    }
}
```

---

And this is `mainmenu_fragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="@string/mainmenu"
        android:onClick="showMainMenu" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now all i have to do is place the method `showMainMenu(View view)` somewhere. I thought this would go in the corresponding java file (MainMenuFragment.java in my case). But it only works when i put the method in the MainAvtivity.java file.

That means that all my button actions from all kinds of fragment layouts will go in one (the main) java file. Why can't i simply place it inside the java file that calls the Fragment layout..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answers is (like already pointed out), you can't.

The only way to do this is by creating an onClick even listener. In the MainMenuFragment.java in the onCreate method, do something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_fragment, container, false);

    Button menuButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
    menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("app", "onclick listener");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

You can remove the onClick attribute from the layout xml.

Answer (score 2):

Now all I have to do is place the method showMainMenu() somewhere - this is wrong. Please, refer to the documentation of [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) :

For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) **method of your context** (typically, your Activity).

Seems You cannot place your callback *somewhere*, because framework won't be able to find that callback. If You're defining it inside Activity (which is actually, a Context), it's possible for View to find it back. Actually, View.java contains the following code:

```
case R.styleable.View_onClick:
    if (context.isRestricted()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot " + "be used within a restricted context");
    }

    final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
    mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName, View.class);
    ...
    mHandler.invoke(getContext(), View.this);
```

Seems it's the only possible way to call callback defined in layout file with current android:onClick attribute specification.

Comment: I'm not sure if i follow. I know that the method must receive a `View view` as parameter. The problem just is, that i can only place the onClick method in my `MainActivity.java` file. But it's `MainMenu.java` that loads the fragment layout. I just want to know if that file can handle the onClick event instead.

Comment: Provided some more details with actual android View sources.

Comment: The answer remains the same - it's just impossible to call it, because current android code and Activity-Fragment fundamental differences. Please, check Fragments documentation - it's not the same as Activity and it's not related to the context.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following:

Fragment xml contains

`android:onClick="myFunction"`

Activity Contains

```
public void myFunction(View v)
{ getSupportFragmentManager().findViewById/Tag(...).myFunction(v); }
```

Fragment Code can then implement as below to have access to local data

```
public void myFunction(View v) {...}
```

Hope this helps.